# @NotEmpty, @Size Java 1.5 annotations not working - Maven

Tags: java, maven, annotations, dependencies

I'm building a maven project, and trying to use Java annotations with Java JDK 5. I have an endpoint that I'm passing an object to. I am trying to verify a certain String within that object of it's size, and for it not to be empty.

```
@POST 
@Path("path") 
public Response endpointMethod(@NotNull Object object) { 
        return Response.status(Status.OK).build(); 
}
```

In my Object class:

```
@NotEmpty
@Size(max=20, message="size is greater than 20")
public String var;
```

If the object is verified to be not null, then the endpoint will just return a 200 OK response. However, when I fire a request to this endpoint, with the specified path, and nothing in the body, there are no errors that are thrown. Instead, I am able to retrieve the 200 response (even when I check if the object is null before return the response, it shows that that is the case).

I've raised a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854304/notnull-annotation-not-working-as-expected-java-jersey) about this before, with a similar issue, and to resolve that, I had to add a jersey-bean-validation dependency in my pom.xml which solved it. However, the environment to which I am deploying my application to does not support jersey, and such I cannot use the same dependency.

Therefore, am I missing a dependency in my pom.xml? At the moment, the annotations are not being picked up. Please let me know if you need more information, or if the above is not clear.

Comment: Does it support hibernate validator?

Comment: Yes I believe it does.

Comment: You can then achieve the same result using hibernate-validator and using `@Valid` on your endpoints.

Comment: Is there a maven dependency for that? What if I want to validate against a regex pattern for example (using @Pattern)? I don't just want to validate the object, but some of the variables within it as well (I've been able to do that with jersey-bean-validation).

Comment: Yes there [is](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.3.0.Alpha1). You can do some pretty crazy stuff with custom validators and if I remember correctly it has its own `@Pattern` for regex.

Comment: I've tried to include the dependency in my pom, but the validations still aren't being picked up for some reason.

Comment: Are you using Spring? Spring does this pretty seemlessly... otherwise try [this](http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/)

Comment: No luck either. I've tried adding the dependencies in EL, but the validators aren't being picked up. Also, I see that this requires java 6 or more? I need something compatible with java 5.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Adam, did you find any solution? How you fixed it?