# @NotNull @QueryParam("String") String not working in jersey validations

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am trying to use javax.validation.validation-api for validating @QueryParam parameters. I am new to jersey so, don't know much about it, check the code below

Code:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/{services/SuperWeb}")
@ValidateOnExecution
public String getBranchName(@PathParam("name") String name,
    @NotNull @QueryParam("phone") String phone,
    @NotNull @QueryParam("email") String email) {

    try {
        //Some code where I should not check the phone and email is not null...
    } catch(Exception exception) { 
        throw new ...

    }
    return "";
}
```

Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@NotNull annotation not working as expected Java Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854304/notnull-annotation-not-working-as-expected-java-jersey)

Comment: I think we have similar question here. Please use different search keywords before posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check to make sure you haven't set any of these in your Jersey configuration, in the class extending ResourceConfig.
If yes then please make it false to enable the validation. Just try
once else past your web.xml for for more help.

```
CommonProperties.FEATURE_AUTO_DISCOVERY_DISABLE, 
ServerProperties.FEATURE_AUTO_DISCOVERY_DISABLE,
ServerProperties.BV_FEATURE_DISABLE
```